# plot if datapoint time is missing python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization

I have a dataframe that contain weekly data.sample is attached below.

[image]

What I want to do is, plot a chart to indicate if any seconds' missing.Here 2020-06-19 11:48:35 is missing. So I want to indicate missing time points in the whole dataset in the plot.

My plan is to create another dataframe with a column called "type" and put 0's available timepoints and 1's for non-available timepoints. Then plot a line chart. But I have no idea how to create this dataframe including non-available points.

Answer (score 1):

Missing data updates the original data frame by creating time series data at the frequency required by the minimum and maximum time series values of the original data frame. `df.reindex()` is used.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
time WindSpeed
"2020-06-19 11:48:32" 3.11
"2020-06-19 11:48:33" 3.37
"2020-06-19 11:48:34" 4.28
"2020-06-19 11:48:36" 5.34
"2020-06-19 11:48:37" 5.87
"2020-06-19 11:48:39" 6.03
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='1s'))
df.plot(kind='line', lw=2, color='b', marker='o', grid=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks . What does mean by lw=2?

Comment: and another thing is when the dataset is large, its hard to find this missing line, is there any way to highlight that missing points?

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach, but I think adding a marker would be a good idea.

Comment: `lw=` is linewidth